# Array is not initializing correctly in foreach loop

Tags: c#, random, generator

So I am trying to make a random number generator:

```
private static void init() 
{
    int[] integ = new int[10];

    Random random = new Random();

    // init
    foreach (int integer in integ)
    {
        integ[integer] = rand.Next(5,35);
    }


    foreach (int b in integ)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Byte = " + b);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    init();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

But for some reason, when I run it,it prints this:

```
Byte = (*random number here*)
Byte = 0
Byte = 0
etc...
```

I run it multiple times to make sure, and every time only the first one has a non zero number.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You have initialized an array with `Length` 10 but all with default values which is 0 for `int`. So you're always overwriting the first `int`(`integ[0]`). You want to use a `for`-loop to initialize all values in the array.

Comment: `foreach (int integer in integ)` yields 10 times 0. Use a `for` loop.

Comment: read the doc for `foreach` it does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @TimSchmelter But isn't the first foreach supposed to do that?

Comment: @Mechanic45: no, that's a `foreach` which always yields `0` since the array contains only zeros, hence always overwites index 0: `integ[0] = rand.Next(5,35)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok I am confused. Isn't foreach supposed to loop through every cell of the array one after the other? What does their value ( = 0) have to do with it?

Comment: @Mechanic45 `foreach` loops over `integ` and the value of `integer` is the value of each elemnt of the array, not the index. As integ is intialise as an array of 0s then `integ[integer]` is always `integ[0]`

Comment: @BenRobinson Oh I see. So there is no way to initialize the rest of the array using foreach then?

Comment: @Mechanic45: only if you use an additional counter variable which you increase in the loop. But you should really use a for-loop since it was designed specially for this purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at what this does:

```
foreach (int integer in integ)
{
    integ[integer] = rand.Next(5,35);
}
```

Basically, a [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx) loop iterates through the *values* of `integ` (which are all initially `0`), and sets that value at that index in `integ` to a random number. So it will only populate the first item in the array.

To initialize the array, use a [`for`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) loop instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < integ.Length; i++)
{
    integ[i] = rand.Next(5,35);
}
```

Or if you're comfortable with a bit of Linq:

```
Random random = new Random();
int[] integ = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10)
                        .Select(i => random.Next(5, 35))
                        .ToArray();
```

And as *Blindy* points out, if all you want to do is print the values, you don't even need the array:

```
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Byte = {0}", rand.Next(5,35));
}
```

Comment: Don't even need the array if all you're doing with that enumerable is print it out.

Comment: @Blindy True, but I presume OP is planning to write more code to use this array after this point.